# Foreach Loops in PHP - All or nothing

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-5, stripe-payments

In a foreach loop, say I wanted to do the following

```
foreach($items as $item)
{

  // charge a user for purchasing an item - IS BEING DONE THROUGH AN API CALL WITH STRIPE
  // ie: \Stripe\Charge::create(...);

  // save some info to a database
  // using Laravel for this project so this is within a DB::transaction(...);


  // send a notification email to the buyer
  // Emails are being queued to avoid slowing down the request
  // ie: Mail::queue(...);
}
```

I would like an all or nothing situation to occur. For example, if an error occurs during the iteration, then NONE of the items are charged, no information is saved to the database, and the buyer does not get a notification email. However, if the foreach loop successfully iterates over each item, then charge the user, save info to database, and send notification email. How do I do this?

Comment: Will the same buyer be notified for all of the items?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I think this should be handled as a transaction.

Comment: anyone recommend a try catch block somewhere??

Comment: @ArvinFlores are all the items for one buyer?

Comment: Yes, but the sellers will more than often be different. Which is why i have this running in a foreach loop. A coworker had suggested something like parallel processes for this, but im not too familiar with how that stuff works.

Comment: Ok, the as you may see in the answer it is better to send the notification at the end, that way you can send one notification for all the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Transactions and notifying the buyer at the end.

Mysqli Example:

```
$dbConn->begin_transaction();

try{

    foreach($ítems as $item){
        //Whatever you are going to do
    }

    if($dbConn->commit()){

    //Notify buyer about all the transactions, the user doesn't receives the notification unless the commit was succesful

   }

catch(Exception ex){
    $dbConn->rollback();
}
```

Additionally you could verify the return values of the mysqli functions, I Just wanted to focus on the transaction use.

Comment: Good to bring up transactions but what do you say about the notification email?

Comment: Check the result of `$dbConn->commit()`

Comment: Right but, say the second commit fails, OP doesn't want the first email to go out. I think with the transaction, you capture what the OP needs better than my answer but you need to account for the email.

Comment: That's right I am assuming all the items are for one buyer, otherwise why would we need to check for errors in separate checkouts. Just guessing.

Comment: Oh I see it now. The commit is outside the loop! +1 from me

Comment: In this example, the foreach loop must iterate successfully over each item otherwise an exception is thrown??

Comment: That is right, if any exception is thrown the transaction will rollback.

Comment: I also see you are calling an API, then you should validate the response and throw an exception if it's erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add some more detail as per @Terminus as well as if/why you are charging each item separately. But depending on your needs, you could build the db query during the loop without executing it until the end of the loop. You would then have to roll back any charges (as per your implementation) and then send one or more emails as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the no of items in the array and make some changes to make it work:

```
$result = count($items);
$c = 0;
foreach($items as $item)
{
// charge a user for purchasing an item -- instead add it to a buffer as total 
//amount.
// save some info to a database ---instead prepare your db statements here
// send a notification email to the buyer.--this could be sent out for all the 
//items in the order together outside the loop instead of inside the loop.
$c = $c + 1;
}
if($c == $cc)
{
//execute your prepared statements here..and also the other email and charging stuff.
}
else{
 //Error code. 
 }
```

Comment: I am assuming here that the items in the loop belong to the same buyer.

Answer (score 0):

You have options.

Easiest way i can think of is loop over the array twice; the first time checking the condition and the 2nd only if the first run through found no problems.

```
$isGoodToGo = true;
foreach($items as $item) {
  if (conditon met) {
    $isGoodToGo = false;
    break; // stop iterating over the array cause condition is met
  }
}

if ($isGoodToGo) {
  foreach($items as $item) {
    // charge a user for purchasing an item
    // save some info to a database
    // send a notification email to the buyer
  }
}
```